# Format columns AND Enable Outlining in protected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I use following code in excel so that I can Outline with + and - in protected sheets.

Now I also want to format columns (and/or cells) in these prtected sheets. Is this possible?

Kind regards,
Ricco

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 For Each Sheet In Worksheets
 Sheet.Unprotect Password:="riccowendy"
 Sheet.EnableOutlining = True
 Sheet.Protect Password:="riccowendy", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
 Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on following sub.

```
Sub DoOutline()
 For Each sht In Worksheets
    sht.Unprotect Password:="riccowendy"
    sht.Cells.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    sht.Cells.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With sht.Cells.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    sht.Protect Password:="riccowendy", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Doen't work for me. (it changes format). I just want to format columns if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Google "vba excel change format on protected sheets" did help with this:
[learn.microsoft.com ... allowformattingcells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.protection.allowformattingcells)

```
Sub ProtectionOptions()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="riccowendy"

    'Allow cells to be formatted on a protected worksheet.
    If ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowFormattingCells = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="riccowendy", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

 MsgBox "Cells can be formatted on this protected worksheet."

End Sub
```